# Splitting a table cell into two columns in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following table:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Header</th>
    <th scope="col">Header</th>
    <th scope="col">Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td scope="row">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Split this one into two columns</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I wish to split the cell which contains "*Split this one into two columns*" into two cells/columns. How do I go about this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ha9e/)

Comment: Define “split into two columns”. Which columns? If you mean you want to add a column to the table and move part of the cell content to the new column, what might be the problem then? Just add the column, by adding one cell to each row.

Answer (score 56):

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/8ha9e/1/

Add `colspan="2"` to the 3rd `<th>` and then have 4 `<td>`'s in your second row.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Header</th>
    <th scope="col">Header</th>
    <th scope="col" colspan="2">Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <!-- The following two cells will appear under the same header -->
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think I would rather add the 4th column header since it will probably need it based on OP's real data, most likely, and use `colspan` on the `<td>` element, instead.

Answer (score 33):

I came here for a similar problem I was facing with my table headers.

@MrMisterMan's answer, as well as others, were really helpful, but the borders were beating my game. So, I did some research to find the use **rowspan**.

Here's what I did and I guess it might help others facing something similar.

```html
<table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px; font-size: 0.8em;" border="1px">
    <tr align="center" >
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 10%;" rowspan="2">Item No</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 55%;" rowspan="2">DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px;" rowspan="2">Quantity</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px;" colspan="2">Rate per Item</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px;" colspan="2">AMOUNT</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Rs.</th>
        <th>P.</th>
        <th>Rs.</th>
        <th>P.</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This answers a completely different question.

Answer (score 22):

You have two options.

1. Use an extra column in the header, and use `<colspan>` in your header to stretch a cell for two or more columns.
2. Insert a `<table>` with 2 columns inside the `td` you want extra columns in.

Answer (score 6):

Change the `<td>` to be split to look like this:

```
<td><table><tr><td>split 1</td><td>split 2</td></tr></table></td>
```

Answer (score 3):

is that what your looking for?

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <th scope="col">Header</th>
 <th scope="col">Header</th>
 <th scope="col" colspan="2">Header</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>Split this one</td>
 <td>into two columns</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this example, you can split with the `colspan` attribute

```
<TABLE BORDER>
     <TR>
         <TD>Item 1</TD>
         <TD>Item 1</TD>
         <TD COLSPAN=2>Item 2</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
         <TD>Item 3</TD>
         <TD>Item 3</TD>
         <TD>Item 4</TD>
         <TD>Item 5</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

More examples at http://hypermedia.univ-paris8.fr/jean/internet/ex_table.html.

Comment: the problem with this is how do i sort both the tds on clicking the table header,

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following way.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does this add to the numerous answers that already use colspan?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Header</th>
        <th scope="col">Header</th>
        <th colspan="2">Header</th>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td scope="row">&nbsp;</td>
        <td scope="row">&nbsp;</td>
        <td scope="col">Split this one</td>
        <td scope="col">into two columns</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does this add to the numerous answers that already use colspan?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/SyedFayaz/ud0mpgoh/7/

```html
<table class="table-bordered">
  <col />
  <col />
  <col />
  <colgroup span="4"></colgroup>
  <col />
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">
      S.No.
    </th>
    <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">Item</th>
    <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">
      Description
    </th>
    <th
      colspan="3"
      style="horizontal-align: middle; text-align: center; width: 50%"
    >
      Items
    </th>
    <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">
      Rejected Reason
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Order</th>
    <th scope="col">Received</th>
    <th scope="col">Accepted</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>Watch</td>
    <td>Analog</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>Not Functioning</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2</th>
    <td>Pendrive</td>
    <td>5GB</td>
    <td>250</td>
    <td>165</td>
    <td>85</td>
    <td>Not Working</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question; OP asked for colspan, not rowspan, and asked for it on a td, not a th.