# Is there a way to slice a tables TD into 2 editable sections?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to have a TD be able to have 2 entries entered into it separated by a line

td will look like in web page 1 td with 2 separate sections)

```
val/tot
 ___ ___
| 6 | 5 |
 --- ---
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not 2 tds, since you are already using a table?

Comment: I don't think BatuZet's question was rhetorical. If there's a reason why you can't use two tds, it's actually probably relevant context to include in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115560/splitting-a-table-cell-into-two-columns-in-html

Comment: I am writing a scoring App where I have a column for a score.
That column has a current score and then a cumulative score.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, I think a solution is to strategically use colspan on the headers so a single header covers two columns.

Based on your comments, I think a solution is to strategically use colspan on the headers so a single header covers two columns. See my example for what that might look like.

The combination of table-layout:fixed and word-wrap:break-word keep the cell from widening when the value changes, instead the text will wrap vertically. I put a really big value in the example to show this.

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
table{
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:200px;
}
.score {
  width:50px;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2">Team 1 Score</th>
  <th colspan="2">Team 2 Score</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>Val</th>
  <th>Tot</th>
  <th>Val</th>
  <th>Tot</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
  <td class="team1score currentScore score">50000000</td>
  <td class="team1score cumulativeScore score">10</td>
  <td class="team2score currentScore score">3</td>
  <td class="team2score cumulativeScore score">6</td>  
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you.
When I type in the values, the rows expand. Is there a way around this. Tried setting up a width="50", but did not work.

Comment: @motti10 I've modified the CSS to make the table-layout fixed and the cells wrap long entries. It's one way of keeping everything inside the cell but letting the height change rather than the width. Ultimately, the options are pretty much a) expand the cell one way or the other, b) put the value inside a scrollable container, c) cut it off if it overflows, or d) set up the editing so that the number of characters is limited.

Comment: Thanks.. Is there anyway to have it be like the following:

                   | Team 1 | Team 2 |
= 
    Event| Lane | val |tot|  val | tot | lane|event
=

Where only the vals are colspanned...

thanks

Comment: Sorry , it formatted badly. My question is can I add on left/right of Val\Tot <Th> othere headers  keeping the team score 1/2 in place

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Team</th>
    <th scope="col" colspan="2">Score</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Boston</th>
    <!-- The following two cells will appear under the same header -->
    <td> 10 </td>
    <td> 10 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you.I have made the rows editable.
When I type in the values, the rows expand. Is there a way around this. Tried setting up a width="50", but did not work.