# Html table design with multiple cell

Tags: html, tabular

I want to design a table such as picture given below.I tried a lot but not same as this table. Please help me anyone.

[image: Table Image]

Comment: colspan/rowspan are the attributes to look at.

Comment: use `colspan` and `rowspan`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a table cell into two columns in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115560/splitting-a-table-cell-into-two-columns-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `rowspan` and `colspan`, here's a jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/LLpms06w/1/